# Nested UITableview row height not getting updated perfectly in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I'm working with nested UITableView in one of my application to implement the Accordion view. I have implemented three level of nesting in the tableview. 
It works perfectly in iOS 7 and earlier version, but have the issue in iOS 8.

Following are the screenshots for both versions i.e iOS 7 and iOS 8 :

iOS 7 Screenshot
[image: iOS 7 Screenshot]

iOS 8 Screenshot :
[image: iOS 8 Screenshot]

For sake of convenience I have given different colour to identify the tables.
Also I would like to mention that I have used Custom tableview cells with NIB file.
There are 3 UITableviews(Outer Regional Table- Blue colour, subsequent inner Location Table- Green colour and the innermost User Table- Yellow Table).

When I Click on the Location tableview Sectionheader (A green strip which starts with location name Head Office)I fetch the number of users under that location (my execution control is in LocationTableviewCell, earlier i have mentioned the use of NIB for tableview cells). Depending on the number of users I calculate the height for the location table row for that section, and then i also have to calculate the outermost table row height as it has to accommodate the new rows(users) created. For calculating the outermost tableview height I have used Protocol implementation as I can't update the GUI of outermost(Regional tableview) because the execution control is in LocationTableViewCell file. Problem is that in iOS 8 the Users list is getting hidden as the outermost tableview's(Region tableview) row height is not getting updated.

Sorry for the long explanation, but I can't paste the code as it is distributed in the three files and even if i would have tried to add code here it would have looked messed up.

Please if can anyone resolve the issue i'm facing. Its working in iOS7, then why it is so that same code not working perfectly in iOS 8.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you share the code

Answer (score 2):

you might setting cell height through your delgate method. in iOS8 cell height set automatically. check this link http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells

Comment: Hello, made changes in my application as suggested, but still the problem prevails.tableView. I deleted the heightForRow method and added following code. 
estimatedRowHeight = 68.0;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
I'm not sure whether its due to auto layout issue or something else.
Will you plz suggest what might be the issue that need rectification.

Comment: Now the row height is 44.0, which is the default height of the tableview row.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the problem occuring due to nesting.please check the link given below.

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)